# On Groups of Maximal Class: Reference

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I will be happy if one gives references (oncluding current research) for `classification' (structure) of $p$-groups of maximal class which contain abelian maximal subgroup (i.e. abelian subgroup of index $p$).

I couldn't find the references online or in books of Y. Berkovich.

(Thanks in advance!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the study of $p$-groups of maximal class really kicked off with this paper:

> Blackburn, N.
>   *On a special class of p-groups.*
>   Acta Math. 100 1958 45–92.

These days the basic source is:

> Leedham-Green, C. R.; McKay, Susan (2002), *The structure of groups of prime power order*, London Mathematical Society Monographs. New Series, 27, Oxford University Press.

If you can't get hold of these email me and I'll send you an e-copy.